Japanese manga about a young male MC becoming a hero in another world and coming back to earth after defeating the demon Lord
It is a Japanese manga. Art is normal manga style and black/white.
MC is a male lead.
MC became a hero in another world and came back to earth after defeating the demon Lord.
MC is lowkey an S-class hero and a young guy.
In the current earth, there is a hunter system.
Stumbled upon it months ago but I've forgotten the title. Help please.

This is an answer posted as a question. I don’t think I’ve seen that before

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What exactly are you saying here?  Are you looking for a similar, but different manga?  Is the title just a red herring?

I could see a possibility that they're actually trying to follow the "if you think you are talking about the same work, post your own question and maybe reference this one" advice we give.  Except... my answer was accepted.

After OP's edit, looks like it's a manga identification. I've tried clarifying the title for reopening, but wondering if the detail is too generic.

its a reverse isekai. i cant remember title but here are the other details i do remember: mc is back in japan and its 2040. mc is in someone elses body. mc's body was thrown off of the school roof by bullies. mc came from japan but before smartphones so he has to learn how to use a smartphone. there is a hunter guild for closing portals to the demon monster world. an a-class young hunter girl takes interest in mc. a bunch of hunters double cross and try to murder mc. i want to say his name is "takeru"?

Kyuuseishu ≪Meshia≫~Isekai Wo Sukutta Moto Yuusha Ga Mamono No Afureru Genjitsu Sekai Wo Musou Suru~
mc was summoned to another world and executed after killing the demon lord. he wakes up in the body of someone in japan. there is a hunter system for dealing with demon gates.
found by search : reverse-isekai takeru . its helpful to remember mc name :D
